# Grunt/JSHint installation error

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-jsxhint

Im new to development and im using Steven Foote's book "learning to program" im currently trying to finish a portion of the project that requires you to install Node.js and Grunt. I seem to be having a problem with installing grunt.. hope the following makes sense.

i Installed Node.js

now im moving towards installing NPM, but first i navigate to the directory:

```
/Users/MR/Desktop/kittenbook
```

then i execute the command `npm`

the command seems to execute correctly, based off the books output results.
the next command i entered is, and receive the following error:

```
Mannys-MacBook-Pro:kittenbook mannyr$ ~/Desktop/kittenbook/ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
-bash: /Users/MR/Desktop/kittenbook/: is a directory
```

so instead i'ved tried:

```
Mannys-MacBook-Pro:kittenbook mannyr$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

i receive the following output:

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)
```

here are my files:

```
GruntFile.js

module.exports = function(grunt){
    // project configuration
    grunt.initConfig({

        concat:{
            release: {
                src: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js'],
                dest:'release/main.js'
            }
        },
        copy: {
            release: {
                src: 'manifest.json',
                dest: 'release/manifest.json'
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            files: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js']
        }
    });
    // we will load grunt plugins here
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

    // we will register tasks here
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'copy']);

};


package.json

{
    "name": "kittenbook",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "devDependencies":{
        "grunt":"~0.4.2",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0"
    }

}
```

when i try running the following command i receive this issue:

```
Mannys-MacBook-Pro:kittenbook mannyr$ grunt jshint
Warning: Task "jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you are giving, you only installed:

- Node
- NPM
- Grunt Client

The error message you are getting is because the dependencies in your `package.json` are not installed:

```
    "grunt":"~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0"
```

Go to the directory where `package.json` exist and run `npm install`. It will install these packages and then try `grunt jshint`. It is supposed to work.

Comment: my kittenbook directory is as follows:

`GruntFile.js
js (Directory) 
manifest.json

node_modules  directory(installed with npm im assuming)

package.json

release (directory)`

Answer (score 0):

issue was the file name GruntFile.js, should have been Gruntfile.js