# I get an error when I run grunt jshint

Tags: gruntjs

I'm also going through Steven Foote's book *Learning to Program* and am currently on chapter 4, which uses Grunt. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952533/grunt-jshint-installation-error) has a similar problem, but the problem is different (this person capitalized the "f" in Gruntfile.js).

I've seemed to have installed NPM and Node properly

```
npm@5.10.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

andrews-macbook-air:Kittenbook Andrew$ node -v
v8.11.3
```

Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        release: {
            src: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js'],
            dest: 'release/main.js'
        }
    },
    copy: {
        release: {
            src: 'manifest.json',
            dest: 'release/main.js'
        }
    },
    jshint: {
        files: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js']
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.registerTasks('default', ['jshint', 'concat' 'copy']);
```

In checking to see if I did it correctly I run grunt jshint in the command line, but I get back an error

```
andrews-macbook-air:Kittenbook Andrew$ grunt jshint
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected string
Warning: Task "jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Try changing `grunt.registerTasks(...)` to `grunt.registerTask(...)`  (i.e. delete the trailing `s`)